# Gitflow with extra supporting branch

Tags: git, devops

First a little introduction about the project.

We're creating a WebApp that will contain "Building Blocks" with the goal to make multiple(read 100+) customer websites. All the websites are build using the same source. Each website will have a customer folder(in the source) were we put "customer specific files" like (images, theme.sass & `.vue` files). In this customer folder there are no "Building blocks".

We're working with DevOps for the first time and want to use the git branching model Gitflow with a little tweak. Next to the default branches we like to add a Customer branch this branch will directly branch to to the Releases branch. Why? Our customers need to test and approve their website. When a customer approves the website we will merge to the Develop branch and to the master so the website is put to production.

Why not using features branches for this? Well you will always commit a feature to Develop. And if for example Customer 1 didn't approve yet but Customer 2 did you can't deploy because customer 1 is also in the develop branch.

To make things more clear
[I've created this model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3wQg.png)

Is this the right way to tackle this problem?

Comment: exactly.I think they confuse concepts of features, frameworks, configs.....

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Because the Customer website is build with the main app, and using components from it. When we for example update a component/building block we like to update all the customer websites which are using this.

We need to have the customers folder in the source, so we can build the website including the customer files.

Comment: So why not use a package manager or [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)? If you have 100+ customers with images, you will hit Git limits in your repository very soon. Not even to mention your CI/CD...

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Hmm Submodules sounds interesting and maybe just what we need thanks!. I'm going to test with that. Is this going to work when we want to build with DevOps? The images I'm talking about are not that many (a logo, few icons). Some users will have "packshots" but these we will put on a cdn.